# There is a confusing issue in for loop on Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, variables, arraylist

This code:

```
user_data_list = [['Full Name', ' Email Address'],['Blossom Gill', ' blossom@abc.edu'],
                  ['Hayes Delgado', ' nonummy@utnisia.com'], ['Petra Jones', ' ac@abc.edu'],
                  ['Oleg Noel', ' noel@liberomauris.ca']]
old_domain_email_list = ['blossom@abc.edu','ac@abc.edu']
new_domain_email_list = ['blossom@xyz.edu','ac@xyz.edu']
for user in user_data_list[1:]:
    for old_domain, new_domain in zip(old_domain_email_list, new_domain_email_list):
        if user[1] == ' ' + old_domain:
            user[1] = ' ' + new_domain
print(user_data_list)
```

The result:

```
[['Full Name', ' Email Address'], ['Blossom Gill', ' blossom@xyz.edu'], ['Hayes Delgado', ' nonummy@utnisia.com'], ['Petra Jones', ' ac@xyz.edu'], ['Oleg Noel', ' noel@liberomauris.ca']]
```

I really don't understand why the value of `user_data_list` list changed in this code.
As i can see, just the user variable that was unpacked in the for loop is changed when the if statement is true.

i have tried the same code and i adjust my_list list a bit differently. But the result is different than above code, my_list list did't changed

```
my_list = ['a','b','c','d']
old_my_list = ['b','d']
new_my_list = ['repalce_1','repalce_2']
for i in my_list:
    for old_, new_ in zip(old_my_list,new_my_list):
        if i == old_:
            i= new_
print(my_list)
```

The result:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: What is your goal in changing the value of `user` ? Since once the `for loop` ends the variable is no more usable.

Comment: This is a code inside my exercise. I don't understand why the user_data_list changed while i just change user variable. How is the user_data_list related to the user variable in this case?

Comment: It is cause both are pointing to same `memory address` check my answer below you will understand better.

Answer (score 1):

Though it unpacks, behind the scenes it is referring to the same element hence it is being effected. Look at the `memory address` it is poiting to the same in the below code.

```py
user_data_list = [['Full Name', ' Email Address'],['Blossom Gill', ' blossom@abc.edu'],
                  ['Hayes Delgado', ' nonummy@utnisia.com'], ['Petra Jones', ' ac@abc.edu'],
                  ['Oleg Noel', ' noel@liberomauris.ca']]

print("External id -", id(user_data_list[0]))

for item in user_data_list:
    print("internal for loop id -", id(item))
    break

# Output
# External id          - 2306933340288
# internal for loop id - 2306933340288
```

Comment: Let me check. Thank you.

Comment: my_list = ['a','b','c','d']

old_my_list = ['b','d']

new_my_list = ['repalce_1','repalce_2']

for i in range(4):
    print(id(my_list[i]))
for item in my_list:
    print(id(item))
    for old_, new_ in zip(old_my_list,new_my_list):
        if item == old_:
            item = new_

print(my_list)

`output`
`2616457977072`
`2616457684720`
`2616457678128`
`2616457677872`
`2616457977072`
`2616457684720`
`2616457678128`
`2616457677872`
`['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`
With this code, i checked **id** of all element and seen that they are the same. But `my_list` didn't change. Why?

Comment: With your code when you are performing `item = new_` you are just updating a variable of `str` type. If it were `list` type then it would have effect

Comment: Welcome, please accept my answer so it would be useful for others too :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Abhi's answer, you can work around this behaviour by creating a deepcopy of the list. This will have a different memory address

```py
from copy import deepcopy

user_data_list = [['Full Name', ' Email Address'],['Blossom Gill', ' blossom@abc.edu'],
                  ['Hayes Delgado', ' nonummy@utnisia.com'], ['Petra Jones', ' ac@abc.edu'],
                  ['Oleg Noel', ' noel@liberomauris.ca']]
original = deepcopy(user_data_list) # 140007211377088 
# OR use the one below.
original = user_data_list[:] # 140007211479424
print(id(user_data_list))
print(id(original))
old_domain_email_list = ['blossom@abc.edu','ac@abc.edu']
new_domain_email_list = ['blossom@xyz.edu','ac@xyz.edu']
for user in user_data_list[1:]:
    for old_domain, new_domain in zip(old_domain_email_list, new_domain_email_list):
        if user[1] == ' ' + old_domain:
            user[1] = ' ' + new_domain
```

Comment: It doesn't work, since internal list are again pointed to same memory address. `print(id(user_data_list[0]))` & `print(id(original[0]))`  gives `2306944206784` & `2306944206784`

Comment: I checked it.
with original = deepcopy(user_data_list) that it work ok. print(id(user_data_list[0])) & print(id(original[0])) gives 1896202655680 & 1896207125120
But with original = user_data_list[:] that it pointed to same memory address. print(id(user_data_list[0])) & print(id(original[0])) gives 1661051688896 & 1661051688896